# how to get a really nice finish on wood as a beginner?

Tags: finishing

In tons of videos, ([random YouTube example](https://youtube.com/shorts/ODqyRj_PW8Y?si=wwsPui6Hy_RaaRVs)) the wood transforms into something totally different with a finish.

I can't for the life of me get anything even remotely as nice as those things. At best I get a small change in colour, but never have I been able to "buff out" the wood grain so much. What are these people using and what is the trick to get it right? Is the secret in the coating or in the wood (or both)? How much of this is editing and they're actually applying multiple layers? Should I use a piece of cloth or a brush? How much should I use?
I have so many questions, but in the end I just want to have results like that. I'm looking for basically the "top 5 steps to get started and get reasonably good results".

Clarifications: I've tried different finishes sold in my local DIY store, none come even close. Results I've gotten so far range from barely visible over brown smudges to essentially paint that covers everything up. I'm looking for this "buffing" effect, where the wood looks professional, the grain shows through, and it's an even coating. I'm not looking for a specific protection or something, right now my focus is on visuals.

I'm a beginner, got a few tools but not yet a complete shop and mostly experience on practical things like an outdoor enclosure for my cats and stuff.

I've worked mostly with rough wood, I've tried sanding it with whatever sand paper I happened to have, I've tried polishing it (bought a polishing set for my grinder). I've tried an oil and a varnish from the local DIY store, both picked for colour without any understanding of ingredients. Yes, I'm a beginner. :-)

Comment: Welcome! What finishes have you tried, and on what woods? And how did you prepare the surface? (Planing or sanding, if sanding, then to what grit?)

Comment: From my experience, which is limited to oil and shellac on pine, beech and white oak, the finish does accentuate the grain. In fact, simply wiping the wood with water or alcohol does so as well. I do think the effect can be exaggerated depending on how the light catches the surface, and to some extent due to video production as well. Also something to note, once the finish dries, the results are often not as pronounced as when you have just applied it.

Comment: Keep in mind that an outdoor piece of furniture will definitely require a protective finish (of which paint — although it obscures the grain — is a prime example) and a careful choice of wood species. When I think of outdoor projects, the kind of “in your face” finish you describe is not what first comes to mind :)

Comment: @stanch I've added some more clarifications to the question. Also yes, I'm now asking mostly for indoor projects. The catio is just the biggest woodworking project I've done so far, and for which I bought some tools I didn't have before.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to have a picture of the results? It is difficult to say what is wrong with your finish based solely on the fact that it’s “barely visible”. Actually some oil finishes are designed for a “natural look”.

Comment: OK, quite a few things here. First, please don't post blind links as some people won't open them for various reasons; add at least a brief description of where the link goes to. Now to your query, you're asking *way* too much here as an experienced SEer should know, a Q that has no definite focus is extremely hard to Answer, because it's amorphous. Additionally the basic underlying query here (in essence, the title) is way too subjective for the SE model — trust me when I tell you this, people can have ENTIRELY different ideas on what a good finish on wood actually looks like! [contd]

Comment: It's not just about smoothness, enhancement of grain but also (can be) very much about surface finish. And popular styles in recent years have provided an excellent example of this, with a widespread acceptance of a frankly dull finish which most older woodworkers would have been very *very* disappointed with. Good, even great, colour/grain enhancement but without any significant gloss = something being very much duller than it could be

Comment: Now about hardware store ingredients and finishing in general, good finishing doesn't have to be about expensive materials. Far from it. An ordinary oil-based poly available at just about any hardware store or home centre is capable of producing a range of excellent results (very good looks, with at least decent protection) *with almost no effort*. Also, in the US/Canada, where premade shellac is widely available and affordable that's another fine example — apply shellac the right way and you get French polish, and French polish has been considered the queen of finishes for 100+ years

Comment: @Graphus all those points are excellent pointers, thanks. I'm really a beginner, so my questions is necessarily broad. I don't yet know what *exactly* I want or need. I just want it to look good without a full apprenticeship. Some basics are probably all that's needed (for now).

Comment: Just a thought - for some woods, you just won't get any great effect, no matter how hard you try, it's just dull, maybe shiny dull, but nothing exciting. So maybe try a different wood species (like cherry for example)

Comment: *"so my questions is necessarily broad."* There are other resources for bringing yourself up to speed, including reading all the prior Q&As here but it's well worth going back to primary sources for all things woodworking related — the many, many good books on the subject (a decent number of them available for free on Archive.org or Project Gutenberg). If you want to ask broadly scoped questions online and get into conversations about the options, various ways you might proceed, workarounds etc. then a conventional discussion forum is the correct venue.

Comment: Finishing in particular is best understood in a ground-up way, i.e. best picked up from primary sources that take you through principles in steps, so you don't fall into various traps that can occur picking things up piecemeal. In addition to less easily getting a cohesive & consistent picture of things when you pick stuff up here or there you automatically glean it from sources of variable authority... and no matter where you are, that will also include confusing, misleading or outright false info. Hopefully learnt from books you'll be insulated from that issue, even if not all equally good.

Comment: @Graphus I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry for the misunderstanding. I am not looking for a carpentry apprenticeship. I'm doing a small bit of woodworking with limited time and resources. I don't want to nor do I have the time to understand all the small details of every small part. I'm really looking for beginners advise to get somewhat nice results. I understand a pro will always beat me. I don't aspire to become a pro. I just want my small side projects to look a little bit less amateurish.

Comment: Well there are abundant resources (understatement!) for new woodworkers online, including here in Woodworking — we've had many prior Questions here about the basics, the Answers cover a lot of beginner territory and are just a search or two away. But so so much of the online content is geared to those new to the craft, and some even specifically intended for first-time woodworkers..... which neatly leads on to a search recommendation, try *first-timer* and *finish* as search terms here, and *first-timer* and *wood finishing* in a general web search and see what comes up.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that to get the best results, you would need to be deliberate about two things:

- how you prepare the surface
- how you choose the finish

For surface preparation, the first thing is to get the wood flat. You can buy it flat (rather than rough), you can take it to a commercial shop to get flattened, you can use a hand plane (lots of videos on YouTube) or machines (ditto).

If you go with a hand plane, you *might* be able to skip the next step, which is sanding. Again this needs to be more deliberate. E.g. start with 80 grit, move to 120 grit, then to 180 grit. Draw pencil lines across the entire board so that you can check your progress (i.e. when the lines disappear). Search on YouTube for “how to sand a board” :)

For the finish selection, I recommend you to read one of the many finish comparison posts on the internet, pick *one* finish and try to get better with it. My first pick was shellac — it looks good but is definitely not fool-proof. Something like a hardwax oil (e.g. Osmo) can be more fool-proof, although I am sure more experienced woodworkers might take an issue with this recommendation! (Note that neither of those is outdoor-proof!!!)

This depends on where you live, but I would not necessarily trust the local DIY store to carry a good finish. Or good sandpaper for that matter. Check the many sandpaper comparison videos on YouTube. I like 3M Cubitron.

For ultimate results, the common recommendation seems to be to read this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Wood-Finishing-Comprehensive-Troubleshooting/dp/1565235665](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565235665).

Comment: Thanks. So it seems I cheaped out on everything that matters, both the sanding and the finish as well as the products. Dang, I didn't want to make a science out of it, but this gives me a start on what to be more careful with.